# NSCLIENT++ Unattended Installation + Allowed Hosts

Tags: unattended, nsclient++

For the best of me I just cant get it to install properly.
I have dozens of Win servers to deploy this thing but the nsclient.ini never updates at the end of the installation.

This is what I'm running which is found just about anywhere on the net:

> msiexec /i NSCP-0.4.1.102-x64.msi /passive /norestart /ADDLOCAL="ALL"
>   REMOVE="NSCAPlugin"

I also tried the older version:

> msiexec /i NSClient++-0.3.9-x64.msi /passive /norestart ADDLOCAL="ALL"
>   REMOVE="NSCAPlugin" ALLOWED_HOSTS="10.204.204.204"

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the `/passive` flag at the end. Same goes for the `/quiet` flag.

```
msiexec.exe /i "\\Path\to\NSCP-X.X.X.X-x64.msi" /norestart ADDLOCAL=Plugins,MainProgram,FirewallConfig,DotNetPluginSupport,ProductFeature,CheckPlugins,NRPEPlugins,NSCPlugins,NSCAPlugin,ExtraClientPlugin,SampleScripts ALLOWED_HOSTS=127.0.0.1,$IP_OF_NAGIOS_SERVER CONF_NSCLIENT=1 /passive
```

While GP management is a great solution, it does not answer the question posed. The above code has been used to deploy in my environment successfully.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, you should be deploying the ini file from group policy or some tool like altiris/wpkg/gpo/sccm so when there is a change it is either pushed or pulled but it gets applied and the nsclientpp service gets restarted. You can also use psexec from sysinternals and a custom script to do this.

Plus points if you keep the ini file in version control ;-)

Comment: That's smart thinking right there my friend!
Thanks